# Save Response as variable and send it as Header - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, get

I'm currently working on sending a GET request to my own private Domain, alongside
various Headers that would be populated with various values such as 'Token' etc. - that are base64 encoded. This is running perfectly fine.

**My main goal here is to send the Response of another request i'm sending to a different endpoint.**

#### This is the modified code (I've removed various fields so please ignore any best practices for now).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const net = require('net');
const os = require("os");
const dns = require("dns");
const https = require("https");

var token = process.env.HOME+'/token.txt';
let base64data1 = '';
try {
        if (fs.existsSync(token)) {
                var data1 = fs.readFileSync(token,'utf8');
                let buff1 = Buffer.from(data1);
                base64data1 = buff1.toString('base64');
}} catch(error) {
        console.log('')
}

var options = {
    hostname: "myprivatedomain.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Token": base64data1
    },
};
var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

req.on("error", (e) => {
    // console.error(e);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

#### My goal, as mentioned, is to add additional Header (In addition to the "Token" header) to my private domain, which will be populated by the **Response** for the following domain - [www.seconddomain.com](http://www.seconddomain.com)

I was thinking about creating a simple function that would retrieve the response, save it as variable and use it as my 2nd Header. Something similar to this -

```
function 2ndresponse(url) {
        let data = '';
        http.get(url, (resp) => {resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                        data += chunk;
                });
        });
        let responsevalue = Buffer.from(data);
        base64data = responsevalue.toString('base64');
        return http.get(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

var = 2ndresponse("http://www.seconddomain.com");
```

Hopefully this is clear enough (:

#### Update

I figured it out -

The workaround is to set both request in one function like so -

```
function req2() {
  http.get({
  hostname: 'seconddomain.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/blahblah',
  agent: false}, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';
    res.on("data", (d) => {
      var x;
      x = d;
      let buff5 = Buffer.from(x);
      seconddomainvalue = buff5.toString('base64');

    var options = {
        hostname: "myprivatedomain.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Length": postData.length,
            "token":  tokenvalue,
            "seconddomain":  seconddomainvalue
        },
    };

    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        res.on("data", (d) => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });

    req.on("error", (e) => {
        // console.error(e);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
    });
  });
}

req2();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved using the HTTP REQUEST also, But AXIOS allows us to make HTTP requests from both the browser and Node. js applications. It allows us to make both GET and POST requests which are the most used HTTP methods.

```
const axios = require('axios'); // Axios import
const controllerFunction = async () => {
    const firstResponse = await axios.get('https://seconddomain.com'); // Here the request will wait, as it is synchronous
    
    const bufferValue = Buffer.from(firstResponse.data);
    const base64data = bufferValue.toString('base64');
    
    const secondResponse = await axios.post('https://myprivatedomain.com', {"body": data}, {
         headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Token": base64data
      }
    }); // Here the second request can use the first request response data, as this code is executed synchronously
};
```

Also adding the AXIOS documentation link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Ok so i'm guessing something similar to this -
const axios = require('axios');
const controllerFunction = async () => {
    const firstResponse = await axios.get('http://seconddomain.com');

    const bufferValue = Buffer.from(firstResponse.data);
    const base64data5 = bufferValue.toString('base64');

    const secondResponse = await axios.post('myprivatedomain.com'>
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "imdsv": base64data5
      }
    });
};

Comment: does not seems to work =/ i'm not getting any POST

Comment: I didn't get that, you want to use POST?

Comment: sorry for not being clear -
there are 2 requests that are being send.
the 1st (needs) to be send (GET) to the seconddomain.com, recieve the response, save it as variable.
the 2nd request is a POST request to privatedomain.com where I be posting the various data i've collected and send it via the headers. So in the end the POST request to my privatedomain.com will contain a Header with the value of the response of the 1st GET request.

Does it make more sense now ?

Comment: @Dorbenshitrit I updated the answer based on ur comment, Now in the POST method you can be sent your data as well `{"body": <here you can give your post data JSON>}`. Please check the answer now.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help! but i'm still not able to see the request coming through.

Comment: could this be solved by properly setting a global variable ?

Comment: Global variable on what purpose, can you please update the question with your current code changes based on Axios in a way that I can run it in my local.

Comment: can i reach out directly via email ? it won't let me chat with you